# How to create react-native app for route like uber, with the use of HERE-MAP?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, here-api

installed 'npm install react-native-heremaps --save'

This is for react-native init android, I tried some application using ios concept.

**Error**

Loading dependency graph, done. Error: Unable to resolve module `./index`

**Referrence:**

[Github ios sample](https://github.com/Andriiseer/react-native-here-maps)

Answer (score 0):

this question is a bit vague for SO, something that would require an entire course to answer. Currently it looks like you should learn how to do react-native android before attempting to add on top HERE. There are many great tutorials to get that started and working.

For the here portion you will have to use the Here-Maps-SDK. Since there isn't a react version of this SDK, you will need to link it using a react bridge.

It's not that easy of a process, and will take a decent amount of work to get right.

Here are some examples to help get started: https://hackernoon.com/react-native-bridge-for-ios-and-android-43feb9712fcb

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios